# Get id of subscription by name

Tags: azure, arm

I'm writing an Azure ARM template and for a vnet peering I need to reference a resource from another subscription:

```
"remoteVirtualNetwork": {
  "id": "[resourceId('42b899ee-f51a-46ed-aebe-62fe141fc3fe', 'network-shared-rg', 'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', 'some-vnet')]"
}
```

How can I use the name of the subscription instead of having to specify its uuid?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't, you need to specify the ID. The subscription display name is not a global unique identifier and so cannot be used.